# what is the use of @ (At) in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I got this lines of code in Excel.

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1 :="=Support started"
Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=FindStart([@Created])"
```

In the excel sheet there is a column called `Created`, but when I use the same code with the same data in a different Excel sheet, it does not work. It throws an error just here `Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=FindStart([@Created])"`

So, is this [@Created] referring to a column or is it used as a parameter in Access or SQL statment where you pass it as a parameter?

Comment: That is Table formula syntax. There must be an Excel table(not just a regular data table, but a special Excel Table) which has such a column name

Comment: I think it means that created is defined as a decimal datatype. Just as if you have used dim created as decimal. Could be wrong though :-) $ is for string for instance.

Comment: Look up "Structured References" - E.g.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error could occur because of the version of the Excel file you have. Try to use this instead:

```
Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=FindStart([@[Created]])"
```

The difference is between this `[@Created]` and this `[@[Created]]`. You need to change it to the later.
Normally @Created is used as a parameter, and in this case it is referring to a column in your sheet.